# React Native Android Reload JS does not restart activity as Enable Live Reload

Tags: react-native

We have a React Native project version (0.23.3). Recently we started having issues with Android developer menu's "Reload JS" option. It fetches the bundle (I see Loading JS bundle) but does not restart Activity so we cannot see our changes immediately. On IOS cmd + R works great. If we manually restart activity are JS bundle changes are there.

Any idea what might be going on.

Comment: Your version of react native is quite old. Maybe you should cosider updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue, We had some code in MainActivity that was stopping it from restarting, After fixing it it works, Thanks for your response